# Error when pushing to vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a pointer to vector of vectors thats defined as this,

`vector< vector<Edge*> >* adj;`

and initilized,

`adj = new vector< vector<Edge*> >(v, vector<Edge*>());`

When I push back to this vector of vectors,

```
Edge* e = new Edge(v, w);
adj[u].push_back(e);
```

I get an error,

```
prog.cpp:27:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<Edge*> >::push_back(Edge*&)’
  adj[u].push_back(e);
                ^
```

I dont understand whats wrong with this, I'm using it correctly right?

Comment: why pointer to STL containers? !!!

Comment: Is u an index number? And why are you using a pointer to a vector rather than the vector itself?

Comment: I already feel sorry for this code.

Comment: Are you coming to C++ from C#? Did you mean `vector<vector<Edge>> adj(v);` instead of `adj = new vector< vector<Edge*> >(v, vector<Edge*>());`?

Comment: `adj[u].` is indexing from the pointer-to-vector-of-vector - allowed because the compiler trusts you have an array of such pointers, whereas what you actually need is `(*adj)[u].` which indexes in the vector-of-vectors.  If you got rid of the `new`s and pointers completely, you wouldn't be getting yourself confused.

Comment: The vector size is determined at runtime. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @kfsone, only one dimension in the vector of vectors is fixed, the other is dynamic, is that how you do it?

Comment: std::vector doesn't have fixed dimensions, it's a dynamic container. It is *not* like a C# Array.

Comment: Use the functions `reserve` or `resize` to alter the dimension of any given vector. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

Comment: guys, I get that the vector is dynamic. When I create the vector, I provide a size `n`, and I'd like to directly be able to address 0 - (n-1) in one dimension and leave the other dimension dynamic. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If `vector<vector<Edge>>` doesn't solve your problem then you need to be more clear about exactly what the problem is. But do it in another post, because the question in this post is already answered by the first part of Mark's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adj` there is a pointer, so you need to dereference it first:

```
  Edge* e = new Edge(v, w);
  (*adj)[u].push_back(e);
// ^
```

But then again, why are you `new`ing and pointifying everything? You can just simply do

```
// Create v amounts of vector<Edge>s
vector< vector<Edge> > adj(v, vector<Edge>());

Edge e(v, w);
adj[u].push_back(e);   // assuming u is a valid index
```

Its much easier to read, less error prone (you don't have to manually `delete` everything), and I'm sure is much more performant than the old version.

**UPDATE:** oh, `e` does not need to be dereferenced.

Comment: The size of the vector of vectors is determined from a constructor, hence adj is a pointer whose size I'm changing at runtime

Comment: @Aks The point of having a `vector` is so you can dynamically resize it. The extra level of indirection of making it a pointer isn't required to achieve this goal.

Comment: @Aks The *size* of a vector is determined by it's constructor, correct, but you are using `push_back` which adds to the vector. `vector`s can grow dynamically. `std::vector<int> v(10); v.push_back(1); v.push_back(2);` creates a vector with 12 elements, 10 uninitialized followed by values 1 and 2. For a vector, `size` is the current number of elements, `capacity` is the maximum number the current memory it allocated internally can store. This value is grown as new values are added.

Comment: @kfsone, so one dimension in my multidimensional vector has a fixed size that I want to reference directly. For eg, I'll provide a size of n and I want to use the first dimension directly from 0 - (n-1). The second dimension will be dynamic. Is there a better way to do this

Comment: @kfsone: "10 uninitialized" - no - in-used vector elements (i.e. indices 0 through size()-1) can't be uninitialised... they're either value or default initialised depending on the type and whether it's C++03 or C++11

Comment: Tony D is correct, they are default initialized, I can't edit my earlier comment tho.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you need a two-dimensional array is leading you astray: there is nothing special about a vector within a vector, it simply has the convenient side effect of looking 2-dimensional.

So lets first look at `std::vector<int>`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Point {
    int m_x, m_y;
public:
    Point() : m_x(0), m_y(0) {}
    Point(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
    int X() const { return m_x; }
    int Y() const { return m_y; }
};

class Edge {
    Point m_start, m_end;
public:
    Edge() : m_start(), m_end() {}
    Edge(const Point& start, const Point& end)
        : m_start(start)
        , m_end(end)
    {}
    Edge(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
        : m_start(startX, startY)
        , m_end(endX, endY)
    {}

    const Point& Start() const { return m_start; }
    const Point& End() const { return m_end; }
};

void dumpEdges(const char* label, const std::vector<Edge>& edges)
{
    std::cout << label << ":"
              << " edges.capacity = " << edges.capacity()
              << " edges.size = " << edges.size()
              << '\n';
    for (size_t i = 0, end = edges.size(); i < end; ++i) {
        std::cout << " edges["<<i<<"] = { "
                  << edges[i].Start().X() << ", "
                  << edges[i].Start().Y() << ", " 
                  << edges[i].End().X() << ", "
                  << edges[i].End().Y() << " }\n"
                     ;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Edge> edges;

    // this has created an empty, dimensionless vector on the stack.
    // when we push something to it, it will internally allocate memory
    // to store an Edge for us.

    dumpEdges("start", edges);

    edges.push_back(Edge(0, 0, 0, 0));

    dumpEdges("added 0,0,5,0", edges);

    // when we now push another Point onto this vector, it may find
    // it has used all the memory it allocated forcing it to allocate
    // more memory. When this happens, our previous "Point" object
    // will end up at a new address. We can avoid issues with this by
    // using index values rather than absolute addresses.

    edges.push_back(Edge(5, 0, 5, 5));
    dumpEdges("added 5,0,5,5", edges);

    // to save the program allocating memory every time we add a new
    // edge, we can predict how many we're going to need.

    edges.reserve(5);
    dumpEdges("reserve'd to 5", edges);

    // watch where the next push_back goes.
    edges.push_back(Edge(5, 5, 0, 5));
    dumpEdges("added 5,5,0,5", edges);

    // but when you use resize, you actually add empty elements:
    edges.resize(6);
    dumpEdges("resize'd to 6", edges);

    // watch where the next one goes.
    edges.push_back(Edge(0, 5, -5, 5));
    dumpEdges("added 0,5,-5,5", edges);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output from ideone.com (http://ideone.com/wP5Rxr):

> start: edges.capacity = 0 edges.size = 0
>
> added 0,0,5,0: edges.capacity = 1 edges.size = 1
>    edges[0] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>
> added 5,0,5,5: edges.capacity = 2 edges.size = 2
>    edges[0] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[1] = { 5, 0, 5, 5 }
>
> reserve'd to 5: edges.capacity = 5 edges.size = 2
>    edges[0] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[1] = { 5, 0, 5, 5 }
>
> added 5,5,0,5: edges.capacity = 5 edges.size = 3
>    edges[0] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[1] = { 5, 0, 5, 5 }
>    edges[2] = { 5, 5, 0, 5 }
>
> resize'd to 6: edges.capacity = 6 edges.size = 6
>    edges[0] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[1] = { 5, 0, 5, 5 }
>    edges[2] = { 5, 5, 0, 5 }
>    edges[3] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>
> added 0,5,-5,5: edges.capacity = 12 edges.size = 7
>    edges[0] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[1] = { 5, 0, 5, 5 }
>    edges[2] = { 5, 5, 0, 5 }
>    edges[3] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>    edges[6] = { 0, 5, -5, 5 }

At this point, you should be armed with the ability to use std::vector, but for your specific use case, you need to remember that std::vector is generic. You *can* wrap another vector in it, `std::vector<std::vector<Edge>>`. But this is just two vectors working independently.

```
void fn()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> adj;
```

`adj` here is a simple, `std::vector` where `adj[n]` resolves to an instance of `std::vector<Edge>`. The two vectors don't really know about each other. The fact that `adj[x][y]` works is convenient magic, it is not a special feature of vector. It would work for any `std::vector<`object-that-implements-operator[]`>`.

When you write `adj[12][7]` what is actually happening is we are taking the top level object, `adj` (type std::vector>`, and calling it's member function`operator`. This returns a reference to the 12th element of the top vector, type`std::vector`, on which we then invoke`operator`. Another way to write it would be:

```
adj . operator[](12) . operator[](7);
```

or

```
auto& object = adj;
auto& outerVectorElement = object.opterator[](12);
outerVectorElement.operator[](7);
```

This code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> adj(5);
```

Creates a `std::vector<T>` and with a *size* of 5. It is equivalent to:

```
std::vector<T> adj;
adj.resize(5);
```

Now, T happens to be `std::vector<Edge>` in the above case. So it creates a vector of 5 vectors.

```
std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> adj(5, std::vector<Edge>());
```

This does something similar but more expensive, it's actually more like this:

```
std::vector<T> adj;
adj.reserve(5);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    adj.push_back(std::vector<Edge>());
```

because that is the syntax for "populate with initial value". It may result in temporary `Edge` objects being created. If all you want is default initialization, and you're sure you want a fixed initial size, just use

```
std::vector<T> adj(N);
```

Some more code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> adj(initialSize);

std::vector<Edge>& firstAdjVec = adj[0];

firstAdjVec.push_back(Edge(1,2,3,4));
```

At this point, adj is a vector of 5 vectors. The first of these now contains a single Edge. We can refer to it either as:

```
firstAdjVec[0];
adj[0][0];
(adj[0])[0];
auto& vec = adj[0]; vec[0];
```

This looks like a 2-dimensional array, but it's not. It is a one-dimensional array of vectors, which themselves each have their own vector data, but they are independent.

If you do this in C/C++:

```
Edge adj[10][12];
```

this allocates one large, contiguous block of memory, 10 x 12. When you use the nested-vector approach, it creates one contiguous block of memory to hold the top level vectors, but each vector will allocate its own independent memory for storing its own elements.

This allows for variable dimensions:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid;
grid.resize(10); // first dimension is now 0-10, all rows are 0 depth.
grid[0].push_back(1);
grid[2].push_back(2);
grid[2].push_back(3);

grid[0][0]; // returns 1;
grid[0][1]; // invalid, exceeds dimensions of std::vector& (grid[0]);
grid[1][0]; // invalid, std::vector& (grid[1]) is empty.
grid[2][1]; // valid
grid[3][0]; // invalid - empty.
```

Lastly the matter of tracking specific edges. Your code used pointers to Edge* objects. Unless you are more familiar with pointers, this is *going* to result in memory leaks. Putting a pointer into a vector does *not* make it the owner for the pointer. You are responsible for returning the memory to the system if you don't want your app to run out of memory. You'd need to use `delete` for this.

Two alternatives: One, don't. Just remove the pointer and have your vector manage the memory.

```
std::vector<Edge>
```

voila. The downside to this is that if you want to keep pointers to these edges elsewhere,

```
void fn(Edge*);
```

you will run into problems when a vector grows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    int m_i;
    char m_pad[1024]; // to make the object big.
    Foo(int i) : m_i(i) { m_name[0] = '\0'; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos;

    // grow the storage to support 4 Foos.
    foos.reserve(4);

    // emplace_back is like push_back but it passes
    // it's arguments directly to the constructor of
    // the new object, initializing it in-place, avoiding
    // a copy. so foo.emplace_back(1) will initialize
    // the new Foo by calling it's constructor with the value '1'.
    foo.emplace_back(1);

    std::cout << "First foo's address is " << (void)&foos[0] << '\n';

    // push 3 more.
    foo.emplace_back(2);
    foo.emplace_back(3);
    foo.emplace_back(4);

    std::cout << "First foo's address is " << (void)&foos[0] << '\n';

    // but now add lots more to force the storage to grow.
    foo.resize(64);

    std::cout << "First foo's address is now " << (void)&foos[0] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

To avoid this, just use indexes instead of pointers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Edge {
    Edge(int i=0) : m_i(i) {} // kill two birds with one constructor.
    int m_i;
};

typedef std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> EdgeGrid;

void pointerVersion(Edge* edge)
{
    std::cout << "pointing to " << (void*)edge << " -> " << edge->m_i << '\n';
}

void indexVersion(const EdgeGrid& adj, size_t x, size_y)
{
    std::cout << "adj["<<x<<"]["<<y<<"] = " << adj[x][y] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Edge>>> adj;
    adj.resize(4);
    adj[1].push_back(1);
    adj[1].push_back(2);
    adj[1].push_back(3);

    pointerVersion(&adj[1][2]);
    indexVersion(adj, 1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you don't always have to push `adj` around in this case, if it's in a class itself, then you just need to tell that class which x and y you want to refer to.

```
class EdgeContainer
{
    std::vector< std::vector< Edge > > m_adj;

public:
    EdgeContainer() : m_adj(10) {}

    // ...
};
```

Better still, you can make this look like a 2-dimensional vector by giving it

```
const std::vector<Edge>& operator[](size_t topIndex) const
{
    return m_adj[topIndex];
}
```

and now you can do:

```
EdgeContainer adj;

// .. code to populate adj here

std::cout << "adj[3][1] = " << adj[3][1] << '\n';
```

Remember, this is actually doing `adj.operator[](3)` which returns a reference to the inner vector, on which we are then calling method `operator[](1)`.